# All non-commited files listed during commit when using Eclipse/Mercurial

Tags: eclipse, mercurial

I'm trying to figure out why Mercurial always lists all the files to be committed even though I selected to do a commit on a specific subset of files or specific folder.

If I right-click on folderX, Team > Commit, I'll see all the files not committed from the rest of the project bundled up with those from folderX. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried *Team -> Commit* from the context menu of a certain package in Package Explorer and MercurialEclipse restricts only the modified files in that package in the Commit dialog. Are you trying this operation from another view in Eclipse?

I still haven't upgraded my plugin from 1.9.4, though, so I can't see if this has changed in a newer version. What version are you on?